# Cannot get field from $_POST array when form has enctype="text/plain"

Tags: php, html, forms, email, enctype

I believe that my code is correct, when I remove the isset statement it returns an error as if the fields were not set. I have heard that this may be due to how PHP is configured on the server which may be the case. It seems like the variables aren't being passed from the HTML to the PHP code. If it means anything I have my PHP installed with WebPlatformInstaller and running IIS on windows server 2016

```
<?php
echo "test";

    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
        echo "success";
        $email_to = "temp@gmail.com";
        $email_subject = "Your email subject line";

        function died($error) {
            // your error code can go here
            echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
            echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
            echo $error."<br /><br />";
            echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
            die();
        }


        // validation expected data exists
        if(!isset($_POST['email']) ||
            !isset($_POST['message'])) {
            died('You must enter your email and a message');       
        }


        $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
        $message = $_POST['message']; // required

        $error_message = "";
        $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

        if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
        }

        $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

        if(strlen($message) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The message you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
        }

        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
        }

        $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


        function clean_string($string) {
          $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
          return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
        }

        $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
        $email_message .= "message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

        // create email headers
        $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
        'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
        ?>

        <!-- include your own success html here -->

        echo "Thank you for reaching out! I'll be in touch.";

        <?php

        }
        ?>`
```

HTML

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name='email' required>
      <input class="btn" type='submit' tabindex="1" value='Send'>
      <textarea type='text' name='message' required></textarea>
    </form>
```

Comment: try to remove: `enctype="text/plain"` or make it: `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

Comment: Just leave the `enctype` attribute off the form unless you're going to be uploading files.

Comment: Also, look into `filter_var` to validate email addresses. Yours will reject valid addresses.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this: [Bug #33741  $_POST superglobal not populated](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33741)
which is about Your issue.

and answer there:

> Valid values for enctype in  tag are:
>
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> multipart/form-data

Check these screenshots with code samples to see results:

**text/plain**

[image: text/plain]

**application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

[image: urlencoded]

EXTRA: **php://input stream**

[image: php://input stream]

as request body it does not change anything but `@` symbol (that's why it's **urlencoded**)

[image: request edit]

RESULT: **It's not a bug of PHP, it's common feature for all PHP versions to accept supported enctypes, it just does not populate `$_POST` array from `php://input` when it "see" different content-type. But if You insist You can read it from `php://input` stream.**

[link to manual](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

Answer (score 0):

why you use enctype="text/plain" ??

HTML forms provide three methods of encoding:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded (the default)
multipart/form-data
text/plain   (Never use)
```

When you are writing client-side code, all you need to know is use multipart/form-data when your form includes any `<input type="">` elements.

Comment: when You write an answer, try to look for reasons why it's not working. Telling that: `text/plain  (Never use)`  is incorrect.  I'm using `text/plain` content-type some purposes where I need to send some un-encoded data to server.